# Perl - Print header in all files with specific extension

Tags: perl

I have multiple input files (outputXXX.pdb) for which I would like to write output files (outputXXX.gjf).

The input files have this format:

```
ATOM      1  CAY GLY X   1      -0.124   0.401  -0.153  1.00  2.67      PEP
ATOM      2  HY1 GLY X   1      -0.648   0.043  -1.064  1.00  0.00      PEP
ATOM      3  HY2 GLY X   1      -0.208   1.509  -0.145  1.00  0.00      PEP
```

For each input file, I would like to create an output file which incorporates a header found in a separate text file 'gaussian.txt' as well as grab the content in columns 2, 6, 7, 8 of each corresponding input file, yielding something like this:

```
Title
Header Line 1
Header Line 2

CAY   -0.124   0.401  -0.153
HY1   -0.648   0.043  -1.064  
HY2   -0.208   1.509  -0.145
```

Below is my current script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

my $input_path  = $ARGV[0];
my $output_path = $ARGV[1];

foreach my $filename (<$input_path/*.pdb>) {

    my $output_file = basename( $filename, '.pdb' );

    open( my $input_fh,  "<", $filename )                       or die $!;
    open( my $output_fh, ">", "$output_path/$output_file.gjf" ) or die $!;
    open( my $header,    "<", "gaussian.txt" )                  or die $!;

    while (<$input_fh>) {
        if ( /CAY/ .. /HT2/ ) {
            print {$output_fh} $header;
            print {$output_fh} join( " ", +(split)[ 2, 6, 7, 8 ] ), "\n";
        }
    }

    close($output_fh);
    close($input_fh);
}
```

It writes the outputXXX.gjf files however does not print the header and does not retain the formatting, not to mention it prints GLOB??

```
GLOB(0x1622950)CAY -0.124 0.401 -0.153
GLOB(0x1622950)HY1 -0.648 0.043 -1.064
GLOB(0x1622950)HY2 -0.208 1.509 -0.145
```

Any suggestions on how to improve my script is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** Updated code below. It's messy (I'm not very experienced), but enables the following output.

Output:

```
 Title
 Header Line 1
 Header Line 2

 CAY-0.124 0.401 -0.153
 HY1-0.648 0.043 -1.064
 HY20.208 1.509 -0.145
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $input_path = $ARGV[0];
my $output_path = $ARGV[1];
my $header = "gaussian.txt";

foreach my $filename (<$input_path/*.pdb>) {
        my $output_file = basename ( $filename, '.pdb');
    open (my $header_fh, "<", $header) or die $!;
        my @lines;
        while (<$header_fh>) {
        push (@lines, $_);
    open (my $output_fh, ">", "$output_path/$output_file.gjf") or die $!;
        print {$output_fh} @lines;
    open (my $input_fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
        while ( <$input_fh>) {
        if (/CAY/../HT2/) {
                print {$output_fh} join (" ", (split)[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
                }
                }
        close($output_fh);
        close($input_fh);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `if (/CAY/../HT2/) `? Do your PDB files always contain exactly those three values in the third column in the same order? Are there other lines in the files that you want to ignore? Also, do you want your output file names to look like `myfile.pdb.gjf`? That is what you have coded, but it would be more usual to *replace* the `.pdb` with `.gjf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$header` does not contain the header string, but its file handle:

```
open (my $header, "<", "gaussian.txt") or die $!;
```

Populate $header with the context of the file instead.

Also, don't print the header before each line.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. The main changes I've made are

- `use autodie` instead of explicitly checking the success of every file operation
- Use a `do` block to read the contents of `gaussian.txt` into `$header`
- *Replace* the `.pdb` file type with `.gjf` instead of adding it to the end
- Use `select` to make the GJF file the default output so that the `print` statements don't need an explicit file handle
- Use `next unless /\S/` to process every line of the input files that contain non-space characters
- Use string interpolation of an array slice to put spaces in the output to avoid the `join` call

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

use File::Basename 'basename';

my ( $pdb_path, $gjf_path ) = @ARGV;

my $header = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'gaussian.txt';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

for my $pdb_file ( glob "$pdb_path/*.pdb" ) {

    ( my $gjf_file = basename($pdb_file) ) =~ s/\.pdb$/.gjf/;

    open my $gjf_fh, '>', "$gjf_path/$gjf_file";
    select $gjf_fh;

    print $header;

    open my $pdb_fh, '<', $pdb_file;

    while ( <$pdb_fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;
        my @fields = split;
        print "@fields[2,6,7,8]\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you help me figure out these errors? `Use of uninitialized value $gjf_path in concatenation (.) or string at ./stack.pl line 21.`
and `Can't open '/output1.gjf' for writing: 'Permission denied' at ./stack.pl line 21` Why would I have trouble with writing permissions?

Comment: @EA00: Is that a question? You have passed no parameters.